# Making fields appear/ disappear using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I am creating some radio buttons and when I click on one of them some fields appear. My problem is that when I click to the next button the fields from the previous one stay on screen while I need them to disappear. This is the code I have written, I know that the reason of my failure is that it never enters the else statement in my javascript function. Can someone help me, I am a rookie in these two languages, is there a way to keep the previous value sent to the function so that I can compare with it for the else statement?
Any other solution would also be well received!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> <title> Ticket Choice </title></HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function IsCheck(but_Check, if_Check){
        if (document.getElementById(but_Check).checked) {
            document.getElementById(if_Check).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else document.getElementById(if_Check).style.display = 'none';
    }
</SCRIPT>

<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(&quot;buttonCheck1&quot;,&quot;ifChecked1&quot;);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck1"> PLANE <br>
    <div id = "ifChecked1" style="display:none">
        <label for = "depart">Departure:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_plane" maxlength = "200"><br>
        <label for = "dest">Destination:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_plane" maxlength = "200"><br>
    </div>

<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(&quot;buttonCheck2&quot;,&quot;ifChecked2&quot;);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck2"> SHIP <br>
    <div id = "ifChecked2" style="display:none">
        <label for = "depart">Departure:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_ship" maxlength = "200"><br>
        <label for = "dest">Destination:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_ship" maxlength = "200"><br>
    </div>

<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(&quot;buttonCheck3&quot;,&quot;ifChecked3&quot;);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck3"> O.S.E <br>
    <div id = "ifChecked3" style="display:none">
        <label for = "depart">Departure:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_ose" maxlength = "200"><br>
        <label for = "dest">Destination:</label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_ose" maxlength = "200"><br>
    </div>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition will never enter on else statement, because always you click on a radio, it will be checked.

Instead, try this:

```
<input type = "radio" onclick = "IsCheck(1);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck1"> PLANE <br>
<div id = "ifChecked1" style="display:none">
    <label for = "depart">Departure:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_plane" maxlength = "200"><br>
    <label for = "dest">Destination:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_plane" maxlength = "200"><br>
</div>
<input type = "radio" onclick = "IsCheck(2);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck2"> SHIP <br>
<div id = "ifChecked2" style="display:none">
    <label for = "depart">Departure:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_ship" maxlength = "200"><br>
    <label for = "dest">Destination:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_ship" maxlength = "200"><br>
</div>
<input type = "radio" onclick = "IsCheck(3);" name = "plane" id = "buttonCheck3"> O.S.E <br>
<div id = "ifChecked3" style="display:none">
    <label for = "depart">Departure:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "depart" name = "depart_ose" maxlength = "200"><br>
    <label for = "dest">Destination:</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "dest" name = "destination_ose" maxlength = "200"><br>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function IsCheck(number){
//here we iterate the three divs
for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    //if the current number (i) is different to the checked input (number)
    if (i != number) {
        document.getElementById('ifChecked'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('ifChecked'+i).style.display = 'block';
    }
}}
```